# Python regex findall function is not working as expected

Tags: python, regex

The regex works in js.

```
let re = /ses-[a-zA-Z0-9]*[_-][a-zA-Z0-9]*?_(.*?)/g;
let result = re.exec('/ieeg_epilepsy/derivatives/brainvisa/sub-01/ses-pre/default_analysis/segmentation/mesh/sub-01_ses-pre_T1w_Lwhite.gii.minf');
console.log(result)
// result is ["ses-pre_T1w_", "", index: 94, input: "/ieeg_epilepsy/derivatives/brainvisa/sub-01/ses-pr…mentation/mesh/sub-01_ses-pre_T1w_Lwhite.gii.minf", groups: undefined]
```

But when I try to translate js code to python code, the result is always a empty list.

```
import res

relative_path = '/ieeg_epilepsy/derivatives/brainvisa/sub-01/ses-pre/default_analysis/segmentation/mesh/sub-01_ses-pre_T1w_Lwhite.gii.minf'
result = re.findall(
    r"/ses-[a-zA-Z0-9]*[_-][a-zA-Z0-9]*?_(.*?)/g", relative_path)

print(result) # []
```

any ideas ?

Comment: `re.findall(r"ses-[a-zA-Z0-9]*[_-][a-zA-Z0-9]*_(.*)", relative_path)`, note `.*?` at the end of the regex always matches an empty string.

Comment: The capture group `(.*?)` does not match anything, and is returned by re.findall. It could be `ses-[a-zA-Z0-9]*[_-][a-zA-Z0-9]*_` instead if you don't want the empty match https://ideone.com/guuvvD

Comment: You have to drop the slashes `/` (and trailing `g`). Besides I don't get why you need the last `(.*?)`